# Interpreting inequalities

Tags: inequality

Two conditions are met for $x$:
$x \geq 4$ and $x \geq 1$

What's the final value of $x$? I believe it is $x \geq 4$, by simple logic if $x$ is said to be greater or equal than $1$ and greater or equal than $4$, then it means it is the greatest one..

However, what's the justification behind this? I cannot just put 'by looking at it' on my notebook.

Comment: Can you show it with the numbers line? ----$0$-----$1$-----------$4$---....now just illustrate the two condition and their intersection, getting $x \ge 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \geq 4$ and $4 \geq 1$, then it follows by transitivity that $x \geq 1$.

So when we say that $x \geq 4$, it is implicit that $x \geq 1$.

So when you write $(x \geq 4$ and $x\geq1)$, that's exactly the same as writing $x \geq 4$. So you might as well just leave it at that.

Comment: Transivity was what I was trying to use! I completely forgot about it!

Answer (score 1):

$x\geq4$ is a subset of $x\geq1$.

Since the condition mentioned is $x\geq4$ 'and' $x\geq1$, the intersection of the two solutions must be taken which is subset of the two.

And hence the final solution is $x\geq4$.